# Evaluation function and coordinate function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Consider the set of all functions from some set $S$ to $\mathbb R$, which is often denoted as $\mathbb R^S$. Let $f\in\mathbb R^S$, that is a function from $S$ to $\mathbb R$. Can we say that the coordinate function $\pi_s:\mathbb R^S\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by the projection on the $s$th component is the same as the evaluation function $\delta_s:\mathbb R^S\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $\delta_s(f) = f(s)$, i.e. is $\pi_s(f) = \delta_s(f)?$

Comment: The _definition_ of $\pi_s$ is the same as the definition of $\delta_s$.

Comment: thank you very much